# Как распознать текст с картинки с помощью ксевил в bas

Tags: xevil

Всем привет!
Вылезла такая проблема при написании бота на кран крипты
Нужно решить капчу

Вот такую - [image: фото]

Пытаюсь решить через xevil, но он либо пишет что капча не решаемая либо возвращает не решения капчи на рандомные цифры и буквы
Как можно исправить данную проблему?
Если решать через rucaptcha, то люди либо возвращают капчу так как она есть, либо пропускают ее, а мне нужно 100% решение